# How to cast a class to an interface using generics in c#?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, c#-4.0, generics, interface

I've this interface:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    List<T> List();
    T Get(int Id);        
    bool Add(T entity);
    bool Update(T entity);
}
```

And I've this class:

```
public class Customer<T> : IRepository<Entities.Customer>
{
   public Entities.Customer Get(int Id)
   {
      var c = new Entities.Customer();
      return c;
   }

   //continue...
}
```

How can I cast a generic class to a generic interface like so:

```
//Other method
public IRepositorio<T> DoStuff<T>(int Id)
{  
   var a = (IRepository<Entities.Customer>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)); // ok               
   var b = (IRepository<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T)); // Exception: unable to cast       

   return object; // an object
}
```

And I call from this MCV controller:

```
  public ActionResult Home()
  {
     var repo = new Repository();
     repo.DoStuff<Customer<Entities.Custormer>>(10);

     return View();
  }
```

My conception is ok? This is possible without dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code supplied, I've tried the following which compiles OK

```
public class Entities {
    public class Customer {
    }
}

public interface IRepository<T> {
    T Get(int Id);
}

public class Customer<T> : IRepository<Entities.Customer> {
    public Entities.Customer Get(int Id) {
        var cliente = new Entities.Customer();
        return cliente;
    }
}

public class foo {

    public static IRepository<T> DoStuff<T>(int Id) {
        var a = (IRepository<Entities.Customer>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        var b = (IRepository<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        return b; // an object
    }

}
```

However, I'm not sure what T is meant to be.  When I run and call

```
foo.DoStuff<Entities.Customer>(0);
```

then I get a runtime error on the `var a` line, because the class `Entities.Customer` does not implement the interface `IRepository<T>`.  If I call

```
foo.DoStuff<Customer<Entities.Customer>>(0);
```

then I get the runtime error on the 'var b' line, because the class `Customer<Entities.Customer>` implements `IRepository<Entities.Customer>` and not `IRepository<Customer<Entities.Customer>>`

Both exceptions are correct, so hopefully the author of the question can work out where the problem lies from this answer.

Comment: Compile for me too, but at runtime raises an "unable to cast exception".

Comment: Then can you post the minimal code that produces the runtime error please?

Comment: I've redrafted my answer.  Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

`Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));` - this creates for you new instance of `T`, which is `Entities.Customer` in your example, but it looks like you want to create instance of `Customer<Entities.Customer>`.